# Why is javascript not taking the async call (async/await)?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, es6-promise

Here is the snippet of my code. I am a newbie to both promises and async/await. I have used multiple questions on SO and articles to read up on the topics. But I can't seem to figure out where I am going wrong. The js file doesn't like the keyword async and this together. Any pointers are appreciated. The resulting error: "Unexpected token function"

```
this.loadTheCategory = async function(catName) {
    var fruitsCategories = null;
    var fruitsArray = null;
    if(jsonString) {
        fruitsCategories = JSON.parse(jsonString);
        var title = null;
        if(categoryCache.get(catName)){
            var isCacheable = categoryCache.get(catName);
            if(isCacheable) {
                title = isCacheable[catName] = "None" ? 100 : null;
            }
        }
        await fruitsCategoryCache.set(catName, fruitsCategories, {title : title});
    }
```

Comment: `async this.loadTheCategory = function` ---> `this.loadTheCategory = async function`

Comment: Maybe this can help you https://nikgrozev.com/2017/10/01/async-await/

Comment: @CRice thank you for your suggestion, but I have already tried that and it didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: @Ariel Alvarado I appreciate you posting that article. It made it much more easier to visualize how promises and async/await works. I think the problem here is more dealing with the keyword this and async in the same line.

Comment: If you are still running into issues, can you edit your post to include the error message you see, or any other details? Otherwise I cannot guess at what is wrong.

Comment: How to you run your code? Do you transpile it with babel?

Comment: @Sylwester yes the code is transpiled with babel.

Answer (score 0):

The `async` keyword should come before the function declaration, like so:

```
this.loadTheCategory = async function(catName) {
    //...
}
```

In your code you used the keyword before the attribution, and that is not valid.

Comment: I have tried that already as mentioned above by CRice, but it's still complaining. Now more so on the keyword "function".

Comment: I don't know which version of javascript you're transpiling from, but you cloud try the syntax `async loadTheCategory(catName) { /*...*/ }` given you are inside a class...